# How to use multiple custom cells (>1) in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I've searched for an answer to this question all over Stack Overflow and have found some useful answers but my situation is different as the number of rows in the section are to be determined from the number of items listed in an array. I'm trying to create a table that uses two custom cells. The first cell displays profile information while the second displays the news feed.

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myProfileDM.profileArray.count
    //return myProfileFeedDM.profileFeedArray.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bio", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

            cell.followerNumber!.text = myProfileDM.profileArray[indexPath.row].followerNumberInterface
            cell.followers!.text = myProfileDM.profileArray[indexPath.row].followersInterface
            cell.following!.text = myProfileDM.profileArray[indexPath.row].followingInterface
            cell.followingNumber!.text = myProfileDM.profileArray[indexPath.row].followingNumberInterface

        return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feed", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

            //let cell: FeedTableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "feed")
            cell.profileFeedLabel!.text = myProfileFeedDM.profileFeedArray[indexPath.row].profileFeed
            cell.profileDateLabel!.text = myProfileFeedDM.profileFeedArray[indexPath.row].profileDate

        return cell
        }


}


}
```

when I run the program, the first cell (with identifier-bio) is the only one that loads/shows up.

Comment: > *the first cell is the only one that loads/shows up.* That would logically happen when `myProfileDM.profileArray.count` is `1`.

Comment: Can you show us what you have in myProfileDM by using NSLog on it and pasting log here ?

Comment: *"the number of rows in the section are to be determined from the number of items listed in an array"* This is the most common thing to do with a table view.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski how do I do this? sorry I'm quite new at this.

Comment: @jtbandes yes I know but I would like for the number of rows in the section to be determined by the number of items in both profile array and profile feed array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the number of rows in the section is wrong. From your variable names I suspect it should be

```
myProfileFeedDM.profileFeedArray.count + 1
```

Note that in the feed array you would have to use `indexPath.row - 1` to get to the right index of your array because the first row is for the profile.

Comment: That's gonna crash on trying to get data in cellForRow until you do -1 there

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski why?? Substantiate your claim.

Comment: array out of bounds ? @Mundi

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Rubbish. That depends on how you implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. He wants one more rows than the news feed.

Comment: @Mundi what I mean is if you just do count + 1 in the code in question - it will crash - as simple as that :)

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski it will, BUT have you read the entire answer? he correctly states that you would have to change the array access as well.

Comment: @luk2302 yes it was edited after my comment, now it's ok :)

Comment: ah okay, sometimes it is annoying and leading to false conclusion if the edit is listed as regular edit :/

Comment: @Mundi I don't know if you noticed but the myProfileFeedDM.profileFeedArray.count is commented out. The reason its commented out is because I get a message saying everything after the first return statement (return myProfileDM.profileArray.count) will not be executed. should I uncomment it and do as you said?

Comment: Of course you have only one return statement, and you should return the correct number of rows - in your case one row for the person, plus the number of news feed items.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reason from the code why it doesn't work.
Try to debug cellForRowAtIndexPath method to see what is the value of the indexPath on each call
(or just put `println ("IndexPath: \(indexPath)")` to your cellForIndexPath method)

PS: But as long as you need your profile cell only once - I would suggest to move ProfileCell into table's or Section's header
it would be a bit more logical I think.